# SP2019 search is not working

Tags: sharepoint-server, search, query, 2019

Created brand new SharePoint 2019 Farm using AutoSpInstaller. In Central Administration, all Search services are showing green. But Search is not giving any results.

ULS log shows below messages:

> 1. "All query processing components are in 'Failed' status."
> 2. "Query processing component 'net.tcp:///QueryProcessingComponent1/ImsQueryInternal'
>      changes its status to 'Failed'"

Following steps are also carried out:

1. Cleared Cache and rebooted servers (app and WFE).
2. Checked all Search Application Services are running.
3. Restarted Search Host Controller service.

   net stop OSearch16

   net start OSearch16
4. Checked all Search services on App server running.
5. Checked search TCP ports - 808, 32843, 32844.
6. Reset index and re-crawled source. Showing success count in crawl log.

Any pointers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search service is ok if you see all Green. Its windows firewall issue.
Windows Server 2019 blocks TCP port 808 even though you see SharePoint Search rule.

1. Create a new inbound rule for TCP port 808 on Application server where Search Application hosted
   a. Give name "SharePoint Search – Query processing"
   b. In Advance tab select Domain
2. Recycle Timer job -

$farm = Get-SPFarm
$farm.TimerService.Instances | foreach {$*.Server.Name.ToString();$*.Stop();$_.Start();}

3. Reset Index
4. Crawl full Search Sources

You'll see search results

Comment: Congratulations on solving this issue and thanks for sharing your solution. You can mark the reply as the answer if you would like.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this problem by restarting the windows search services:

- SharePoint Search Host Controller

```
net stop SPSearchHostController
net start SPSearchHostController
```

- SharePoint Server Search 16

```
net stop OSearch16
net start OSearch16
```

Answer (score 0):

1.Restart the Timer Service in windows services.

2.Reset index in the search service application, then restart all SharePoint search services in "Manage services on server". After all, start a full crawl for your content source, compare the result.

3.If the issue persists, delete the search service application then re-create.

Similar question:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/dca7741e-11c4-459f-9737-74fce92fff74/search-has-encountered-a-problem-that-prevents-results-from-being-returned-if-the-issue-persists?forum=SP2019